# php:how to check if string contains any of the listed keyword?

Tags: php

i have an array of strings.

I have an array of keywords.

i loop through each string, and need to store them to mysql database if it contains any of the keywords.

currently i am using multiple stristr(), which is getting difficult.

is it possible to do something like  `stristr($string, array("ship","fukc","blah"));` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advice you to use regular expresion for that

snipet:

```
preg_match_all('|(keyword1|keyword2|keyword3)|', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

see the documentation of [preg_match_all](http://fr.php.net/preg_match_all) for reference

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ( $strings as $string ) {
  foreach ( $keywords as $keyword ) {
    if ( strpos( $string, $keyword ) !== FALSE ) {
      // insert into database
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$to_be_saved = array();
foreach($strings as $string) {
  foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
     if(stripos($string, $keyword) !== FALSE){
        array_push($to_be_saved, $keyword);
     }
  }
}

/*save $to_be_saved to DB*/
```

Answer (score 0):

try using in_array()

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($arrayString); $i++){

  for ($j = 0 ; $j < count($arrayKeyWord); $j++){

    if (in_array($arrayString[$i],$arrayKeyWord[$j]) == true){
      /* mysql code */

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(in_array($string, array("ship","fukc","blah")))
{

}
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php